# How to create an nearby places android app using Google Place API?

Tags: android

I want to create an android app like nearby places (Shops,travelling places, Restaurants, etc). How to get the basics of Place API for android? Can someone give me any recommendations or ideas?

- App Feathers -

When user opened my app, It's should be show to the user whats near to his place whatever he go.

Any Recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google places Nearby Search lets you search for places within a specified area. You can refine your search request by supplying keywords or specifying the type of place you are searching for.

More details : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro

You can use below API:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Comment: Thanks dude!, I will try

Answer (score 0):

First read and implement [Maps SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start)

and then basically you need coordinates of the places that you want to show user and the location of user. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks dude!, I will try